# Association in Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I have an entity called `Veículo` and another called `Agência`, `Veículo` has many `Agência` and want to make this association. However, when I try to associate the *URI* I get this error. 
Can anyone help me on how to associate correctly?

```
    daniela.morais@tusk:~$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"nome": "Agencia"}' http://localhost:8181/api/agencias
    {
      "nome" : "Agencia",
      "createdBy" : "anonymousUser",
      "lastModifiedBy" : "anonymousUser",
      "createdAt" : "2015-07-17T13:20:10.266+0000",
      "lastModified" : "2015-07-17T13:20:10.266+0000",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/agencias/55a9010a44ae65cbf03ca4c2"
        }
      }
    }daniela.morais@tusk:~$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"nome": "veiculo", "tipo": "tipo"}' http://localhost:8181/api/eiculos
    {
      "nome" : "veiculo",
      "tipo" : "tipo",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a9015244ae65cbf03ca4c5"
        },
        "contatos" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a9015244ae65cbf03ca4c5/contatos"
        },
        "agencias" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a9015244ae65cbf03ca4c5/agencias"
        }
      }
    }
    daniela.morais@tusk:~$ curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type: text/uri-list" -d $'http://localhost:8181/api/agencias/55a9010a44ae65cbf03ca4c2' http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a9015244ae65cbf03ca4c5/agencias
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 17 Jul 2015 13:34:48 GMT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
daniela.morais@tusk:~$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"nome": "veiculo", "tipo": "tipo"}' http://localhost:8181/api/eiculos
```

look at this line. Should `http://localhost:8181/api/eiculos` be `http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos`

or maybe  `http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a9015244ae65cbf03ca4c5/agencias`

should be `http://localhost:8181/api/eiculos/55a9015244ae65cbf03ca4c5/agencias`

it looks like you've got a misspelling/typo that is causing the 404

where `eiculos` is not `veiculos`

Comment: I get the Agência object . There is the method, the Spring automatically generates for me all paths and routes to the correct repositories. But I get a 404 when I try to access http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a9015244ae65cbf03ca4c5/agencias

Comment: There seems to be another problem with the URI

Comment: Thanks but I don't know if in my code works, I have a 204 when I make the PUT request but when I try make a GET request in /api/veiculos/{id} I have a InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException

Comment: if you are getting a new error after updating the typo or after having made some other changes, then could you post the new error along with any changes in an edit to the question?